# Flexbox - last element placement "floating" right

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have to write some grid fallback for IE11.

I want Item 4 to be placed on the lower right so Item 1 can stretch all the way down to the bottom?

[image]

I think this is impossible with flexbox, right? : https://jsfiddle.net/b7w0pc4q/4/

```
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

The SCSS:

```
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #223;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  .item {
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 20px;
    &:nth-child(1) {
      width: 50%;
      align-self: stretch;
      background-color: #a69eff;
    }
    &:nth-child(2), &:nth-child(3) {
      width: 25%;
      background-color: #ffb76f;
      align-self: flex-start;
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
      background-color: #ffee80;
      width: 51%;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
  }
}
```

With a classic float layout it's fairly easy: https://codepen.io/Sepp/pen/MXBrzy?editors=1100 But I don't want to give up yet. any ideas?

Comment: Can edit the html? Or just pure CSS

Comment: Pure CSS. It would work with some parenting I guess. But I mustn't touch the markup because it's only for hacking the layout in IE

Comment: I don't understand. You want to use floats or flexbox?

Comment: I'd like to use flexbox

Comment: I don't see a way without editing HTML and at the same time without at least one `position: absolute`. Are you sure you can't wrap left and right columns in divs, like `.left` and `.right`? It should not affect grid, and would make this layout _flexable_.

Comment: Yeah, flexbox can't do this without an extra wrapper on the "rightside" elements. CSS-Grid can however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I conclude: It is not possible with flexbox without altering the html markup.

Thanks guys.